# Templated operator creates an error stating that the operator is ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I've defined a templated operator to cater for two types of input in the parameter of the operator. The errors come up at getDataFromStream(), how do I define the operator to remove this ambiguity?

BankAccount.h

```
template <typename T>
istream& operator>>( istream&, T&);     //input operator

template <typename T>
istream& operator>>( istream& is, T& aBankAccount) {
//get BankAccount details from stream
    return ( aBankAccount.getDataFromStream( is));
}
```

BankAccount.cpp

## includes "BankAccount.h"

```
void BankAccount::readInBankAccountFromFile( const string& fileName) {
    ifstream fromFile;
    fromFile.open( fileName.c_str(), ios::in);  //open file in read mode
    if ( fromFile.fail())
        cout << "\nAN ERROR HAS OCCURED WHEN OPENING THE FILE.";
    else
        fromFile >> (*this);    //read  all info from bank account file
                 ^^
    fromFile.close();           //close file: optional here
}
```

But is also in this function which provides the errors
(BankAccount.cpp)

```
istream& BankAccount::getDataFromStream( istream& is) {
//get BankAccount details from stream
    is >> accountType_;                     //get account type
    is >> accountNumber_;                   //get account number
    is >> sortCode_;                        //get sort code
    is >> creationDate_;                    //get creation date
    is >> balance_;                         //get balance_
    is >> transactions_;                    //get all transactions (if any)
    return is;
}
```

Cashpoint.cpp
**#includes "Cashpoint.h"(contains #includes "BankAccount.h")**

```
bool CashPoint::linkedCard( string cashCardFileName) const {
//check that card is linked with account data
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open( cashCardFileName.c_str(), ios::in);    //open file
    bool linked(false);
    if ( ! inFile.fail()) //file should exist at this point 
    {   //check that it contain some info in addition to card number
        string temp;
        inFile >> temp; //read card number
        inFile >> temp; //ready first account data or eof
        if (inFile.eof())
            linked = false;
        else
            linked = true;
        inFile.close();         //close file: optional here
    }
    return linked;
}
```

EDIT: Errors in cashpoint.cpp and bankaccount.cpp on operator>>
Possibly to do with the inclusion of BankAccount.h in Cashpoint.h

Comment: can u post exact error from compiler? also post the code where u created instance

Comment: is it being defined for cashpoint wrongly? bankaccount.h is included in cashpoint and the error relates to both their .cpps do i need to overload the definition of operator >> in cashpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Your method of overloading `operator>>` seems strange to me.

```
template <typename T>
istream& operator>>( istream& is, T& aBankAccount) {
//get BankAccount details from stream
    return ( aBankAccount.getDataFromStream( is));
}
```

You are basically saying: no matter what type `T` is, call a method `getDataFromStream` on it. This doesn't make any sense! It is also going to give an ambiguous overload because the compiler now has two `operator>>`s to potentially call when `T` is `std::string`: one from your code and one from the standard library.

It looks like you just want to add an overload for the `BankAccount` type.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, BankAccount& aBankAccount) {
    return ( aBankAccount.getDataFromStream( is));
}
```

Comment: the function getDataFromStream is a virtual function. I need the operator to work for the instance of BankAccount and CurrentAccount.

Comment: @matt9251, if `getDataFromStream` is a virtual function, then the above code will do the right thing.

Comment: yeah the error is that it conflicts with cashpoint.cpp as it states it's ambiguous '>>'. the bankaccount.h is needed in cashpoint.cpp and is included in the header which im pretty sure provides the conflict. for the linkedCard method i would need to define a suitable operator there but currently my attempt provides the same error so im slighlty confused

Comment: @matt9251, have you tried the solution I proposed yet?

Comment: the solution that takes a BankAccount& as a parameter works yeah. that's what I had before I had to cater for the instance of CurrentAccount

Comment: @matt9251, what is `CurrentAccount`? I am afraid you are not likely to get a solution to your problem if you don't provide enough detail.

Comment: also this is one of the error messages:                                            IntelliSense: more than one operator ">>" matches these operands:
function template "std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, T &)"
function template "std::basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits> &std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits> &_Istr, std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc> &_Str)"
            operand types are: std::istream >> std::string ...\5003_Task2a_CashPoint_Skeleton(5)\BankAccount.cp

Comment: there are two types of account, a bankaccount(base class), and a currentaccount(derived concrete class).

Comment: the error only exits with string variables in both bankaccount and cashpoint

Comment: @matt9251, if `CurrentAccount` is a derived class of `BankAccount`, then any function that accepts `BankAccount&` will also accept `CurrentAccount&`. There is no need for templates. So the code in my answer should work fine.